# PNP Provisioning - WelcomePageView in Document Sets

Tags: document-set, pnp-provision, schema

I see that this is now supposed to be supported through the 2018/07 schema? 
There is at least something [there](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/Samples/ProvisioningSchema-2018-07-FullSample-01.xml#L357).

```
              <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview">
            <WelcomePageView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" />
          </XmlDocument>
```

And as this answer by Paolo on GitHub mentions, [it should now be supported](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/issues/190#issuecomment-379706973).

But I am having difficulties finding out exactly how to define and use this in my provisioning template.

Anyone have any insights or examples on how to do this?

Thanks,
Frank

You will need to provide the view ID:

```
       <pnp:XmlDocuments>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview">
            <wpv:WelcomePageView xmlns:wpv="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview" ViewId="c7911cfe-c436-4b90-92a2-a88da10e6bed" />
          </XmlDocument>
        </pnp:XmlDocuments>
```

Comment: looks like it is present in the schema, but has not been implemented in the provisioning engine.

Comment: OK, thank you for feedback. Is there any other way to achieve this? CSOM?

Comment: Looks like it isnt supported via native CSOM as well. Could be wrong here, but i couldnt find a way to make it work unfortunately. Spent some time on it, but couldnt figure out or make sense of how it could be possible :( . Apologies.

Comment: Thanks Gautam, I agree. My findings also indicate that this is not supported.

Comment: as far as I know, this doesnt work.